# How to store word pairs from File to a String?

Tags: c

I have to read from an input file and store word pairs in an dynamic allocated string. We have to create a typedef struct and store the first and the second words seperately

The file looks like this:

```
car couch   \n
  golf ball\n   
mechanic repair\n
```

the pairs are seperated by an whitespace but there can be as many hitespaces before and after the word pair.

In the end I should have 2 strings
"car golf mechanic"
and
"couch ball repair"

```
typedef struct _VocabularyCouple_
  {
    char* first_word;
    char* second_word;
  } VocabCouple;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *fp;
  char* filename;
  filename = argv[1];
  fp = fopen(filename,"r");

  VocabCouple voc_pair[10];

  int count = 0;

  char first_word[10];
  char second_word[10]; //the strings have to start with size of 10 
                   // and then if neede be enlarged by 10

  while(!feof(fp))
  {
    fscanf(fp," %s %s", 1_word, 2_word); // to skip whitespaces ?
    // I don't know how to enlarge if the word is bigger than 10

    voc_pair[count].first_word = 1_word; //?? don't know if right method
  }
}
```

As you can see I am completely lost on how to implement such a thing. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This code does not compile (variable names cannot start with numbers). Please show code that compiles.

Comment: cyberc33, Who or what text suggested code like `while(!feof(fp))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `while(!feof(fp))`.

If the length of files is variable I'd count all the newlines (with `fgetc` or however you like), then seek back to the beginning. Then once you have the line count, you can iterate through it and then use `fscanf` to get your word pairs.

I believe 1_word was a placeholder, but that is an invalid identifier in C, and also not the one you declared earlier (`first_word`).

And `voc_pair[count].first_word = 1_word;` is the correct method, you just need to remember to increment `count` after inserting both the first word and the second word.

I'd also recommend either removing that `filename` variable or moving it's declaration inside a macro, e.g. `#define FILENAME argv[1]`, or just define a constant that has the filename parameter index.

You should also never use `_` at the beginning of a `struct`, or anything for that matter in C, as it is reserved and usually used in operating system code or other things you wouldn't want to mess with.

In regards to enlarging the string if the word is larger than 10 characters, you can use realloc and dynamically allocate a `char*` for words, and insert your own zero terminator. You could clip whitespace characters and insert your own seperator, then read each string into an array.

To skip the extra whitespaces I'd create a separate function that uses `fgetc` with a character variable and a position variable, increment the position variable on each new character. You can then use `isspace` to check if it's whitespace and then discard the character.

Hope this helped!